# Default definitions of foldl' and foldr' seem weird

Tags: haskell, evaluation, fold

Default definitions of `foldl'` and `foldr'` seem weird. They have default definition as:

```
class Foldable t where
    -- ...
    foldr' f z0 xs = foldl f' id xs z0
      where f' k x z = k $! f x z
    -- ...
    foldl' f z0 xs = foldr f' id xs z0
      where f' x k z = k $! f z x
    -- ...
```

Why not?:

```
class Foldable t where
    -- ...
    foldr' f = foldr (\x z -> f x $! z)
    -- ...
    foldl' f = foldl (\z x -> flip f x $! z)
    -- ...
```

Comment: I think that would be roughly equivalent to letting `foldl' = foldl`, losing the strictness. On lists, for instance, you can't implement `foldl'` using `foldl`, but you can when using `foldr` instead. It sounds counter-intuitive, at first.

Comment: @chi, you *can* implement the right semantics for `foldl'` using `foldl` (the OP has done so); what you *can't* do is implement it *well*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, `foldl'` is best for things that look kind of like cons-lists and `foldr'` is best for things that look kind of like snoc-lists. The situations are symmetrical, so let's just look at cons-lists, where `foldl'` had better be good.

You've probably read that `foldl` for cons-lists can lead to space leaks if it's not optimized well enough. Well, that's exactly what will happen here. `f'` is strict, but none of its results are demanded until the fold has reached the end of the list!

The default definitions give a little twist, which makes even naive compilation (or interpretation) work properly.

Comment: So in other words, cons-lists go well with `foldr` and `foldl'`, and thus `foldl'` has default definition using `foldr`? And binary trees won't really matter, right?

Comment: it's a bit unclear to what "here", "`f'`", "its results" and "the fold" are referring. Maybe if you'd included the actual code snippet it'd clarify things.